# Slow mouse button release in Debian stretch

Tags: debian, mouse, mouse-gestures

In the past few weeks (after an update) my touchpad have been acting weird.

Whenever, I let go of the mouse button the system does not register it until several seconds later. This is particular annoying when scrolling.

I couldn't find anything about this anywhere nor any other people having the same problem...

I know very little about the mouse drivers, so I don't know where to begin.

Here is ls -la of /etc/X11/:

[image]

Here is xinput list-props DEVICEID:

[image]

Here are the files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/:

[image]

Here is a pastebin-link:https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/M2y7jQcCz6/ to 40-libinput.conf

Here is a pastebin link:https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xfRjhKvnxV/ to 99-libinput-custom-config.conf

Comment: Could you post `InputDevice` section from the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: I don't have such a file...

Comment: Do you have files inside `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory? Could you post `ls -la /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Comment: I dont' have that folder... I will post ls -la of /etc/X11/

Comment: Detect your devices first: `xinput list`, find `id` number of your mouse, e.g. `id=10` or `id=7`.  Next execute: `xinput list-props 10` - where you have to replace `10` with real `id` number of your mouse.

Comment: Done, and I changed "mouse" to "touchpad" since i realized this may make a difference.

Comment: Ups think I got the wrong ID changed it again.

Comment: Do you have files in the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory?

Comment: Yes - posted, and I will try and post what I think might be relevant from within the files.

Comment: Post content of `99-libinput-custom-config.conf` and `40-libinput.conf` (please, as text, not a screenshot). you can use a `pastebin` service like this: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com

Comment: Ok will try and do that below what I just did.

Comment: Sorry, I'm giving up. There are some contradictions in the information you have posted. I understand nothing.

Comment: Can you tell me what the contradictions are? I understand even less...

Comment: Try to move `99-libinput-custom-config.conf` to your home directory temporarily: `sudo mv /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-libinput-custom-config.conf /home/user/` - reboot your computer afterwards and check if problem is solved.

Comment: I remember now making that file because the touchpad was way to slow - and it is so again after removing it. However, the problem persists so it was not my own meddling... I also tried moving 70-wacom.conf out - no change either.

Comment: I now also tried to plug in another mouse - it does not have the same problem...

Comment: Try to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package and use this settings for the touchpad: https://pastebin.com/JKhpDn3J

Comment: Only replace `MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event15"` with `MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"`

Comment: Tried that now - problem persists...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for delayed button release might be the `Tapping Drag` feature, which is enabled (by default) according to your `xinput list-props` output.

The `Scroll Methods Enabled` might also interfere with the buttons, depending on what the currently-enabled scroll method actually is.

Try `xinput set-prop <DEVICE> 279 0` and `xinput set-prop <DEVICE> 292 0 0 0` to see if either of them fixes your problem.

Comment: Tried both (first one then added the other) can see using list-props that the change took effect, but unfortunately didn't fix the problem...