# right value and way to slow mouse speed touchpad

Tags: debian, input-method

Os= debian stretch (mate). The speed from my mouse is to fast when I use the touchpad.

```
xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (149):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (151): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (279): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (280):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (281):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (282):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (283):  1751, 5191, 1624, 4282
    Synaptics Finger (284): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (285):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (286):   222
    Synaptics Tap Durations (287):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (288):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (289):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (290):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (291):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (292): 101, 101
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (293): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (294):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (295): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.039588, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (296):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (297):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (298):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (299): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (300):   1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (301): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (302):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (303): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (304):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (305): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (306):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (307): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (308):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (309): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (310):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (311):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (312):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (313): 85, 60
    Synaptics Area (314):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (315): 25, 25
    Device Product ID (276):    2, 7
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event1"
```

gsetting

```
gsettings list-recursively org.mate.peripherals-touchpad
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-button-one-finger 1
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad natural-scroll false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-to-click false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-button-three-finger 2
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad horizontal-edge-scrolling false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad tap-button-two-finger 3
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad two-finger-click 3
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad vertical-edge-scrolling true
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad disable-while-typing false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad horizontal-two-finger-scrolling false
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad vertical-two-finger-scrolling true
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad three-finger-click 2
org.mate.peripherals-touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

No xorg.conf present.

```
lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462961/slow-mouse-button-release-in-debian-stretch)

without an accepted answer.

Comment: Which desktop environment are you in?  You can usually rely on your DE setting tools.

Comment: It seems it is not a prblem with speed, more with scrolling behavior. from touchpad I changed some values for scrolling over gsettings and check it if I'm right.  P.S: it is mate environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, it was really scrolling behavior.

```
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad vertical-two-finger-scrolling false
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad natural-scroll true
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad vertical-edge-scrolling false
gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

Now my cursor is not longer flipping around.